# Docker custom networks or network_mode = host which one should I select?

Tags: spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

I have a question regarding using the network_host mode.
I have a 3 to 4 spring-boot services in a docker_compose which I want to communicate with each other. Initially, I was using a custom network for interconnectivity of the services for this I had to specify the host url with each port, but then I found the network_mode host which I think is more easy for me with less code change.
My question is what is the best practice to have a custom network? Or we can use the network_mode host for services to communicate with each other?

Below is my docker-compose file.

```
version: '3'
services:
    redis:                                                                          
       image: redis
       ports:
           - "6379:6379"
    cas-service:
        container_name: cas-service
        image: localhost:5000/cas-service:docker-1.0
        volumes:
             -/DiGiID:/DiGiID   
        ports:
           - "8082:8082"
        depends_on:
            - redis
    eureka-service:
        container_name: eureka-service
        image: localhost:5000/eureka-service:docker-1.0
        volumes:
             -/DiGiID:/DiGiID
        ports:
           - "8301:8301"        
    user-service:
        container_name: user-service
        image: localhost:5000/user-service:docker-1.0
        volumes:
             -/DiGiID:/DiGiID
        ports:
            - "8302:8302"
        depends_on:
              - cas-service
    sftp-service:
        container_name: sftp-service
        image: localhost:5000/sftp-service:docker-1.0
        volumes:
             -/DiGiID:/DiGiID
        ports:
            - "8333:8333"
        depends_on:
              - cas-service
    product-service:
        container_name: product-service
        image: localhost:5000/product-service:docker-1.0
        volumes:
             -/DiGiID:/DiGiID
        ports:
            - "8304:8304"
        depends_on:
              - cas-service
    device-service:
        container_name: device-service
        image: localhost:5000/device-service:docker-1.0
        volumes:
             -/DiGiID:/DiGiID
        ports:
            - "8303:8303"
        depends_on:
              - cas-service
    digiid-service:
        container_name: digiid-service
        image: localhost:5000/digiid-service:docker-1.0
        volumes:
             -/DiGiID:/DiGiID
        ports:
           - "8080:8080"
```

Answer (score 1):

If your services are all declared in the same docker-compose.yml file then you  should connect them directly (service name and internal port), not through the ports mapped on the host. If they are defined in different files then you can still put them on the same network and connect them by service name and internal port.

If you port your docker-compose.yml I can explain better for your situation.

In general, avoid using the host network unless you have no other choice.

Comment: Hi, I have edit the question and added my docker-compose file. What I want to achieve is to connect the micro-services with eureka-service (which is a service discovery and it'll ping all the services using localhost). By using custom_network bridge I am unable to ping eureka to other services, that's why I moved on using network_mode host.

Comment: Is Eureka pinging the services or the services ping Eureka to register and discover? Each service should connect eureka with `eureka-service:8301`

Comment: Services are pinging erueka actually. Yup I can make this change, I was just avoiding to make url changes inside the code of all the services, that's why I was thinking to use the network_mode = host.

Anyways so using the network_mode host is not suggested then ?

Comment: Use the host network as less as possible. Container should not be dependent of external factors (ideally of course). So if you can avoid it, you should.

Answer (score 0):

You scenario looks good for bridge network mode. If you use host network mode, it will take host properties and then you need to isolate your host machine to eradicate any kind of security threats.